# How to count the position of a word in a string whitout counting the html tags

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can i count the position of a selected words o phrase in a paragraph with out count the HTML tags on the string, example.

i have this string:

```
Lorem ipus lores dolores <strong> mauris eget </strong> lectus tincidunt malesuada.
```

i want to know the position of `lectsus` without count or skiping the character of the html tags.

i can not use `indexOf()` because count the character from the tags.

Comment: Use `Node.textContent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick solution would be:

`let index = string.split(' ').filter(x => !x.includes('<')).indexOf(yourWord)`

So what are we doing here?

- `string.split(' ')` takes your string and creates an array with all the words separated by a space
- `filter(x => !x.includes('<'))` takes the array from the previous step and removes all the words that include the character `<`
- `indexOf(yourWord)` simply returns the index of the word you are looking for

This assumes that the words that are not html tags will never include the character `<`.

Of course, you could use more sophisticated HTML sanitizers to identify whether a string is an HTML tag.

Comment: Way more concise than I was writing. You should explain what each part does in case OP or future readers aren't familiar with `.filter()` or lambdas

Comment: what will happen in the case i the tag has attributes...? it will continue woking....? Because i think in that solution work only if the tag have no space between the "< >" and the name of the tag.

Comment: Valid point. You could `filter` again removing `=` and `>` so that you remove all the attributes. This again assuming you don't want/use those characters in your strings